# Interactive Charts: This query could not run because some parameters are not set

Tags: azure-application-insights, azure-monitoring, azure-monitor-workbooks

I want to create an azure application-insights workbook with a Bar chart and a grid. The idea is, when the user clicks on a bar in the chart that the grid filters for exactly that row in the grid. The query for the bar chart is (Set Visualization to Bar Chart in the settings for the query):

```
let Orders = externaldata(OrderDate:datetime, Fruit:string, Weight:int, Customer:string, Sell:int)
[@"https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Castaldio86/a12123a7f0e251a324b176d62deef9b8/raw/02da1d82bc548afc0cf45f7732b456f25d4d8080/Sentinel-Render-SampleData"
]
with(format="csv")
;
Orders
| summarize count() by bin(OrderDate, 1d), Fruit
```

For this, I added a parameter to the bar chart:
[image: parameter configuration]
The parameter will contain all information about the selected row.

In the next query I need that parameter. The query:

```
let row = dynamic({Operation});
let Orders = externaldata(OrderDate:datetime, Fruit:string, Weight:int, Customer:string, Sell:int)
[@"https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Castaldio86/a12123a7f0e251a324b176d62deef9b8/raw/02da1d82bc548afc0cf45f7732b456f25d4d8080/Sentinel-Render-SampleData"
]
with(format="csv")
;
Orders
| where OrderDate == row.OrderDate and Fruit == row.Fruit
```

The problem is, when I don't select any value in the chart it gives message: "This query could not run because some parameters are not set. Please set: Operation".
If I select a value in the chart then the query returns "The query returned no results.".
Would it be possible to have multi-select for the parameter?

Can someone please advice?

Comment: i'm unsure why the other answer was deleted as "plagarism", when it is generally the case that you aren't supposed to just post links to other info as dead links will then make the answer invalid later.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can have a multiselect parameter, which will produce arrays of values (possibly an empty array, which you'll need to account for in the query),

OR, in your screenshot you can fill in the "default value" field to give the parameter a default value when an item is *not* selected.

OR, you can declare the parameter up front (before the chart), and explicitly make it "optional" there (and also "hidden in reading mode"), so that no value resolves to an empty string and things downstream know that is allowed to be empty

Comment: Thanks for the answer
How exactly do I need to apply the filter in the grid so I don't get either the error "This query could not run because some parameters are not set. Please set: Operation" or the error "The query returned no results"? Can you give an example? And as described I want to be able to click on a bar in the chart and it updates the grid. All the examples I have found so far go the opposite way.

Comment: if you're getting that error, then the parameter is somehow marked "required", so the step will wait for a value.  if you want the default value to be empty and not be required at all, you can declare the parameter _before_ the bar chart and mark it not required there, then the bar chart will just overwrite its value when there is a selection.